# Unable to install apk programatically. Installer activity opens and force closes

Tags: android

I am unable to install apk programatically. Installer activity opens and force closes.

```
final File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Optimizer");
File file=new File(dir+"/"+restoreArray.get(0).label);
file.setReadable(true, false);
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(),getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider",file);
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        .setDataAndType(uri,"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Log.i("finalpath",""+new File(file.getPath()));
startActivityForResult(promptInstall,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

That code may work on Android 7.0+. Prior versions of Android did not support `content` as a scheme for installing apps. For those, you have to use `file` and have the file on external storage.

Beyond that, make sure that `file` exists.